# Output also input HTML?

Tags: html, output

I want to be able to use input type="range" which outputs the value but since the users may want to put in specific values it should also have an input type="number". Is there a way to output the range's value in an input box (or in any other way?).

This is the code I've got so far (can't seem to get the output to work aswell somehow).

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="litre.value = (height.valueAsNumber * width.valueAsNumber * depth.valueAsNumber) / 1000">

Height <input type="range" min="135" max="500" id="height" value="200" oninput="outputDimension(value)"/>
<output for="height">135</output>

Width <input type="range" min="135" max="500" id="width" value="250" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />

Depth <input type="range" min="10" max="100" id="depth" value="45" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" />


<div id="sidebar">
    <p>Litre: 
        <output name="litre" for="height width depth">2250</output>
    </p>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you mean. Check the code below. 
After input number inside the box, press `enter`.

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
    }

function updateRange(val) {
      document.getElementById('range').value=val;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input id="range" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">                                                       
    <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" onchange="updateRange(this.value);">
```

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick. I used "oninput" instead of "onchange" instead though. I know that IE9 doesn't support this, so that fix will be for another time ...

Comment: @RolloOlofsson, Glad I could help. you may also vote this if it's helpful.